# Video editing software with Audio scrubbing[Windows 10- 64bit]

Tags: audio

I am looking for a Video editing software to do some post production work on my animated movie(mp4 file without audio).I use Blender VSE,but it lacks severely in effects like transitions ,FX  etc .
My main requirement is **Audio Scrubbing** since their is lipsyncing and precision trimming required in the video.I did do a web search and the only advanced software which seems to pop up is **Adobe Premiere Pro**.Since I am an indie animator, "Premiere Pro" is way of my budget.I also checked softwares like Camtasia,Powerdirector,Movavi,Filmora but was surprised that **audio scrubbing was not available.**
Sony vegas is avalable around the 300$ mark but it seems to be an overkill for just some audio scrubbing .
Are there any other softwares available around the 100$ range with the Audio scrubbing feature and some basic transition,Fx and color grading capabilites.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also suggest DaVinci Resolve for your needs, though you may need the studio version ($300 one time purchase with free upgrades, so far even between major versions.)  While recent versions of Resolve include very full featured non-linear editing and fantastic sound handling with Fairlight audio, I don't believe they include effects and much in the way of transitions.  The paid "studio" version includes a good selection.

You are also getting a pretty high end node based compositing tool (Fusion) built in to the software for that price as well.  Resolve's NLE isn't quite as good as Premiere Pro, but it's very good.  I like Fusion better than After Effects (which is the partner compositor that goes with Premiere Pro.)

Comment: you can get Davinci Resolve Beta for free right now, I did, you should try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Davinci Resolve's editing environment. It's free and, considering that, very powerful. Kind of comparable to the adobe suite, yet less powerful.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation.Davinci is a great software ,surely will give it a try. Also,I have a fairly basic machine ,so the one I found to suit my needs is **"VEGAS Movie Studio 16 Platinum"**.It does have the audio scrubbing feature and also comes with additional softwares like a music maker .It's priced fairly at ~60$ . Check it out @[here](https://www.vegascreativesoftware.com/us/vegas-movie-studio/)